# The operator '>' isn't defined for the type 'String'. Try defining the operator '>'. error in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

i wrote this code :

```
void main() {
  int kian = 40;
  if (kian > 10) {
    print('mamad');
  }
}
```

and now for run I have this error :
The operator '>' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
Try defining the operator '>'.

how can i fix it?
i will be so happy if you answer me :)

Comment: that code is completely correct and running fine. You sure the error is not in some other code?

Comment: The code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were trying to compare two variables which were of type String.

```
void main() {
  String kian = '40';
  if (kian > '10') {
    print('mamad');
  }
}

//Error message:  line 3 • The operator '>'
// isn't defined for the type 'String'.
//Try defining the operator '>'.
```

However, in your question you provided a running code. Check it [here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=8a142d54cba97111b3fe1d154457e0ea).

Answer (score 0):

With the code, it working fine cause it type is `int`. The error may throw from another place.

In case your variable is `String` of number like this `String kian = '40';` you can write your custom **operator** in a **extension** to able to compare them but not recommend. Except you are 100% sure it is an number.

```dart
void main() {
  try{
    print("'40' > '10': ${'40' > '10'}");
    print("'40' < '10': ${'40' < '10'}");
    
    print("'40' >= '10': ${'40' >= '10'}");
    print("'40' <= '10': ${'40' <= '10'}");
  }catch(e){
    print('error. the string is not a number');
  }
}

extension on String {
  operator >(String other){
    return double.parse(this) > double.parse(other);
  }
  operator >=(String other){
    return double.parse(this) >= double.parse(other);
  }
  operator <(String other){
    return double.parse(this) < double.parse(other);
  }
  operator <=(String other){
    return double.parse(this) <= double.parse(other);
  }
}
```

Result

```
'40' > '10': true
'40' < '10': false
'40' >= '10': true
'40' <= '10': false
```